# Changing grid size from css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is an area with equally sized grids. I cannot change the html code anymore but my client wants me to have the middle grid in a different size, so he wants something like col-md-3 col-md-6 col-md-3. Is there anyway to do it through css?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in different ways and the approach depends on how you want the elements renders. I will assume you want to display the three elements on a single row for desktop and on mobile.

**For Bootstrap 3 use**

```
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
```

This will force the 3 divs to appear on same row for both desktop and mobile. For Bootstrap 4 use you can do the same thing like below.

```
<div class="col-3"></div>
<div class="col-6"></div>
<div class="col-3"></div>
```

If you are not using bootstrap, you can use the following Flex css property.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col1"></div>
  <div class="col2"></div>
  <div class="col1"></div>
</div>

<style>
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.col {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
.col2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #666;
}

</style>
```

You can take a look at the solution on this link: https://codepen.io/sirwhite/pen/arXoXG

You can also do this using css grid. checkout the https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: I dont think you understood the question. I cannot change the html anymore.

Comment: oh i see. The best way to do this is through javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can add here an extra parent class to all columns, without editing the columns the new suggested layout can be achieved by using simple CSS only.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
     .cstm-col .col-md-3 {
         width: 25%;
     }
     .cstm-col .col-md-6 {
         width: 50%;
     }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h3>Default Bootstrap Grid</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <h4>.col-md-4</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi suscipit pariatur unde, odio voluptatibus exercitationem quisquam mollitia deserunt necessitatibus esse sunt nostrum eaque consectetur assumenda, dolor ab officiis minima ad!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <h4>.col-md-4</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi suscipit pariatur unde, odio voluptatibus exercitationem quisquam mollitia deserunt necessitatibus esse sunt nostrum eaque consectetur assumenda, dolor ab officiis minima ad!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <h4>.col-md-4</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi suscipit pariatur unde, odio voluptatibus exercitationem quisquam mollitia deserunt necessitatibus esse sunt nostrum eaque consectetur assumenda, dolor ab officiis minima ad!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <style>
        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            .cstm-col .col-md-3 {
                width: 25%;
            }
            .cstm-col .col-md-6 {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <h3>Custom Bootstrap Grid</h3>
    <div class="row cstm-col">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <h4>.col-md-3</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi suscipit pariatur unde, odio voluptatibus exercitationem quisquam mollitia deserunt necessitatibus esse sunt nostrum eaque consectetur assumenda, dolor ab officiis minima ad!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <h4>.col-md-6</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi suscipit pariatur unde, odio voluptatibus exercitationem quisquam mollitia deserunt necessitatibus esse sunt nostrum eaque consectetur assumenda, dolor ab officiis minima ad!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <h4>.col-md-3</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi suscipit pariatur unde, odio voluptatibus exercitationem quisquam mollitia deserunt necessitatibus esse sunt nostrum eaque consectetur assumenda, dolor ab officiis minima ad!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```